# why reactjs setState sometimes rerender old state data?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, xmlhttprequest, axios

After Adding data to database with `Ajax` calls my `TodosList` component must refresh  and show the all todos with the new one added after updating it using another Ajax call (that calls is a php `SELECT *` statement), but that doesn't happen; sometimes it shows the new data and sometimes only old data until I refresh page or added a new todo.

Isn't the role of `setState()` is to update our View with NEW DATA? How do I get that to work? (I added a callback to setState() that it's Console.log(this.state.todos) to see what happen but as I mentioned sometimes todos array got updated and sometimes it doesn't it shows only old data until page refreshed manually or added a new todo) I used `Axios`, and XMLHTTPRequest with promise but same problem .(in console screenshot u can see how array length is not updated sometimes)

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            todos: [],
            currentTodoText: '',
            currentTodoEditText: ''
        };
        this.todoFormTfHandler = this.todoFormTfHandler.bind(this);
        this.todoFormBtnHandler = this.todoFormBtnHandler.bind(this);
        this.todoCheckHandler = this.todoCheckHandler.bind(this);
        this.todoEditTextHandler = this.todoEditTextHandler.bind(this);
        this.todoEditHandler = this.todoEditHandler.bind(this);
        this.todoRemoveCancelHandler = this.todoRemoveCancelHandler.bind(this);
        this.makeRequest = this.makeRequest.bind(this);
    }
    //called whenever app started and when a todo is added to database to refresh results
    getDataFromDataBase() {
        //get all registred todos
        //let requestResult = [];
        /*const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                    const requestResult = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    resolve(requestResult);
                    /*this.setState({ todos: requestResult });
                    console.log(requestResult);*/
        /*  } else {
                    reject({ status: xhr.status, statusText: xhr.statusText });
                }
            };
            xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost/React_ToDo_APP/to-do/src/PHPFiles/SelectAllTodos.php', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xhr.send();
        });*/
        //console.log(requestResult);
        //this.setState({ todos: requestResult });
        axios.post('http://localhost/React_ToDo_APP/to-do/src/PHPFiles/SelectAllTodos.php').then((res) => {
            this.setState({ todos: res.data }, () => {
                console.log(this.state.todos);
            });
        });
    }
    makeRequest = (url, method) => {
        // Create the XHR request
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // Return it as a Promise
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            // Setup our listener to process compeleted requests
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                // Only run if the request is complete
                if (request.readyState !== 4) return;

                // Process the response
                if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 300) {
                    // If successful
                    resolve(request.responseText);
                } else {
                    // If failed
                    reject({
                        status: request.status,
                        statusText: request.statusText
                    });
                }
            };

            // Setup our HTTP request
            request.open(method || 'GET', url, true);
            request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            // Send the request
            request.send();
        });
    };
    componentDidMount() {
        /*this.getDataFromDataBase()
            .then(function(data) {
                this.setState({ todos: data });
                console.log('wttttf');
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
                console.log('lolo');
            });*/
        /*
        this.makeRequest('http://localhost/React_ToDo_APP/to-do/src/PHPFiles/SelectAllTodos.php', 'POST')
            .then((data) => {
                this.setState({ todos: data });
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log('Something went wrong', error);
            });*/
        this.getDataFromDataBase();
    }
    todoFormTfHandler(e) {
        /*used to save whats writed in the field*/
        //const tmpTodoText = e.target.value;
        const tmpTodoText = e.target.value;
        this.setState({ currentTodoText: tmpTodoText });
    }
    todoFormBtnHandler(e) {
        if (this.state.currentTodoText !== '') {
            const tmpTodo = {
                //id: this.state.todos.length + 1,
                text: this.state.currentTodoText,
                isDoneChecked: false,
                isEditable: false,
                isRemoved: false
            };
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                /*if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {

                }*/
            };
            const tmpTodoJSON = JSON.stringify(tmpTodo);
            xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost/React_ToDo_APP/to-do/src/PHPFiles/AddTodo.php', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xhr.send('data=' + tmpTodoJSON);
            /*const tmpTodos = this.state.todos;
            tmpTodos.push(tmpTodo);
            this.setState({ todos: tmpTodos });*/
            this.getDataFromDataBase();

            /*this.makeRequest('http://localhost/React_ToDo_APP/to-do/src/PHPFiles/SelectAllTodos.php', 'POST')
                .then(function(data) {
                    this.setState({ todos: data });
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log('Something went wrong', error);
                });*/
            const tmpTodoText = '';
            this.setState({ currentTodoText: tmpTodoText });
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: i found why nvm